# Drawing profiles using Excel

Tags: microsoft-excel, microsoft-excel-2010, microsoft-excel-2007, charts

I have the data table as shown below.

```
Y-loc  x1-value   x2-value
0.0    0.0        0.0
0.2    50.0       55.0
0.4    65.0       75.0
...
...
2.0    0.0        0.0
```

When I plot it in Excel (Scatter Plot), I get the curves with combined range of x1-value and x2-value on the Y-axis, and the Y-loc on the X-axis.
What I really want is to have the curves turned on their side, with two y-scales, one on the left showing 0.0 to 2.0 in increments of 0.2, and the y-scale on the right showing the range of values at X-locations x1 and x2.

Does someone know how I can do this (in Excel?)

[image]

[image]

Comment: It's not clear what you mean by a y-axis scale "showing the range of values at X-locations x1 and x2".  Could you explain?  The first part of your question (switching the x- and y-axes) is easily done using @Aganju 's technique, or by editing the x- and y-data ranges using the Chart>Source Data... menu.

Comment: Well, a poor and confusing description on my part for sure :-) but the main idea of turning the plot on its side was with correct corresponding X- and Y-values on the axes is what I meant.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need to use the ‘X-Y Scatter Plot’ type, and then switch the X and Y axes.
For that switch, either select them already inverted when creating the graph, or in the existing graph, click on the red / blue line, and edit the shown formula in the formula bar: it will have three parameters, which mean Title, X-data, and Y-data; simple exchange the second and third parameters.

Comment: Thank you Aganju. I had to manually switch the data in the following way: select the "Select Data" option in the "Chart Tool-->Design-->Data" panel; then select each data series and click 'Edit' which gave me the source data panel in which I switched the data.

Comment: Is there no easier way to do this? Basically it seems that I am identifying to Excel, each separate "(x,y) pair" of data-columns to plot, which makes sense, but is there an easier way to do this? Maybe a script?

Comment: In any case, thanks much for your help. Was very helpful.

Comment: And thank you @Mokubai, for editing my post; without your edit, it was all garbage.

Comment: The easiest way is to have your data table arranged with x-values as the first column **before** you create the graph.  This example is a little trickier, since you have 2 columns of x-data.  I would create the graph using x1 Velocity and Y-location (arranged in that order in the data table).  If you select these two columns and have Excel create a scatter graph, the axes will appear the way you want them to be.  After that is done, I'd add a second series using x2 Velocity and Y-location.

Comment: @Badersnatch: Yes, it's an idea I'll try next time. Thanks.